# Сохранение данных из формы в таблице Excel

Tags: javascript, office.js

В общем, необходимо вносить данные, введенные в форме, в документ Excel, при этом каждый раз в новую строку средствами js.

Поискал в интернетах информацию, толкового не нашел. По большей части только формирование каждый раз нового документа. Такой вариант не устроит, потому что с помощью этого документа будет вестись некоторая отчетность. Единственный метод, который я нашел - `Document.setSelectedDataAsync()`, но так и не понял - есть ли возможность дополнения таблицы.

Подскажите, в какую сторону рыть.

Comment: Вряд ли это возможно ))

Comment: Ну подождем, может кто-нибудь знает..

Comment: А почему нельзя записывать данные в другое место: кэш, файл, базу? Когда нужен этот файл для отчетности, то просто его сформировать? Мне кажется, идеально.